# Accessing my edit history

Tags: support, profile-page, suggested-edits

I can access the number edits I made, which were accepted by using this link:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/45756/my-accepted-edits

It shows 43 in number. But currently I don't have any edit privileges, and when I edit the posts, they are peer reviewed by other members.

My questions are:

1. When a question is edited by a user without edit privilege, and when it's peer viewed and accepted by another member, will that question go into the edit history of both users or only the one who suggested it?
2. After I attain 2000 reputation, will there be a edit history tab in my profile, or is the above kind of querying the only way of accessing it?

Comment: [your suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/674374/mithunsatheesh?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) / [reviews of the guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/460368/shikiryu?tab=activity&sort=reviews) who approved [one of your recent suggestions](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/304630)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your suggested edits appear in your activity tab - you can filter your activities to show only [suggested edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674374/mithunsatheesh?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

Your *approved* suggested edits will also appear in your activity stream as [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/674374/mithunsatheesh?tab=activity&sort=revisions) (along with any edits you make to your own posts). Once you hit 2000 reputation, your edits will appear here immediately.

Finally, those who *approve* your edits will gain an entry in *their* activity stream under [reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson?tab=activity).